# Is possible Order Address from distance of user with Geocoder?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i use this code to find address when user typed text, but when user typed address i need order this address result by distance with actual location of user, is possible?

And is possible prioritize addresses from country of user?

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(BuscaEnderecoActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(charSequence.toString(), 10);

List<String> valores = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int k=0;k<addresses.size();k++)
{
    valores.add(addresses.get(k).getAddressLine(0));
}

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(BuscaEnderecoActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,valores);
lstEndereco.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without writing the code for you, this should be possible. Your GeoCoder object is returning a list of Address objects that all have a latitude and longitude populated as a property.

If you know the latitude and longitude of your user, you should be able to calculate the distance between the user and each address in your addresses list, and use that information to sort the list, either using some type of built-in sorting functionality that's native to Android, or with some clever data structure logic.

Hope that helps